# SolrCrudRepository search issue

Tags: spring, solr, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-solr

I am using Spring Boot Application with Spring Data Using `SolrCrudrepository`. I have an entity called `Product` which is used to Store the product Information in Solr. My Question is , i want to get all the ProductIDs from the `Productreposirory`. I know we can use `findAll()` which return a list of ProductEntities but i only need List  which is productids.

```
public Interface ProductRepository extends SoleCrudrepository<productEntity, Integer){

  public List<Integer> getAllProductIDs();

}
```

How can we get only productIDs from the solr collection?

I tried with

```
@Query("Select p.id from Product p)

public List<Integer> findAllProductIDS();
```

Which is returning always empty result set.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fields` property in `@Query` annotation. For instance:

```
@Query(fields = { "id" })
List findAllProductIds();
```

You can read about projections [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-solr/docs/current/reference/html/#solr.misc.projection)